# How can I share Keyboard and mouse between pc and android

Tags: android

I am trying to share keyboard and mouse between pc and android which are plugged in my pc

As I feel irritated to shift my hands between my pc and and mouse and it can increase my testing speed.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an app that can do it. Its available at playstore. [ShareMeow! -Keyboard and Mouse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.share.meow.sharemeow&hl=en&gl=US)